# Extract Numbers and Size Information (KB, MB, etc) from a String in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this

```
"44MB\n" (it can be anything ranging from 44mb, 44 MB, 44 kb, 44 B)
```

I want to separate `44` and `MB` from the above string. I have written this code to extract the number

```
import re
mystring = "44MB\n"
re.findall(r'\d+', mystring)
```

for extracting the size I want to avoid using `if statements` like

```
if "kb" mystring.lower(): 
    # Do stuffs
if .......
```

How can I extract the size info using regex

Comment: Will it always be MB? Please explain more about the pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script:

```
import re


test_string = '44.5MB\n12b\n6.5GB\n12pb'

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([kmgtp]?b)', re.IGNORECASE)

order = ['b', 'kb', 'mb', 'gb', 'tb', 'pb']

for value, unit in regex.findall(test_string):
    print(int(float(value) * (1024**order.index(unit.lower()))))
```

Will print:

```
46661632
12
6979321856
13510798882111488
```

Which is the sizes it found in bytes.

Comment: How would this be if the string has something like `44.50 MB`, `1.5 GB`?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should validate the size strings which you are trying to match:

```
my_string = "44MB\n"
match_Obj = re.match(r'^(\d*)\s?([kmKM][Bb])$', my_string)

print "size: ", match_Obj.group(1)
print "units: ", match_Obj.group(2)
```

**Output:**

```
size: 44
units: MB
```

Here is a link where you can test this regex:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/aH7cF3/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like the following to search for both size and unit (kb, mb)

```
re.compile(r"(?i)(?P<size>\d+)\s*(?P<unit>[km]?b)")
```

Trying it out:

```
>>> rgx = re.compile(r"(?i)(?P<size>\d+)\s*(?P<unit>[km]?b)")
>>> for x in ("44 mb", "44mb", "44kB"):
...     print(rgx.search(x).groups())
... 
('44', 'mb')
('44', 'mb')
('44', 'kB')
```

For dealing with other prefixes, just alter the `unit` portion of the regex.

Its worth noting, since you say case doesn't matter, the "kb" is a valid symbol for kilobit, rather than kilobyte ...